# How to convert a nested complex scala Map to Java

Tags: java, scala, collections

I'm trying to use a Scala library in my Java program and I have some difficulties to convert a complex Scala Map to Java.

My used Scala object method has the following return type: `scala.collection.mutable.Map<String, Map<Object, Seq<Object>>>`

How do I convert that to a Java equivalent of `Map<String, Map<Object, List<Object>>>` ?

I already played around with the JavaConversions and JavaConvertors packages but no luck :(

```
public void getPartitionAssignmentForTopics(final List<String> topics) {
    final Seq<String> seqTopics =         scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(topics).toList();
    scala.collection.mutable.Map<String, Map<Object, Seq<Object>>> map2 = zkUtils
            .getPartitionAssignmentForTopics(seqTopics);

    val map:scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Map[Object, Seq[Object]]] = scala.collection.mutable.Map()
    map:
    collection.mutable.Map[String, Map[Object, Seq[Object]]] =Map()
    map.mapValues(_.mapValues(_.asJava).asJava).asJava
    res2:
    java.util.Map[String, java.util.Map[Object, java.util.List[Object]]] ={}
}
```

This does not compile :)

With playing around I meant that I use the following code to convert from Scala Seq to Java List:
`scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(zkUtils.getAllTopics());`

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "played but no luck"? Have you discovered `JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap`? What was "unlucky" about using it?

Comment: `java.util.Map<String, Map<Object, Seq<Object>>> stringMapMap = JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(map2);` And then convert every item should maybe work?

Comment: maybe it should ... maybe, you should, at least try?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following code. Not really nice :D

```
public java.util.Map<String, java.util.Map<Integer, java.util.List<Integer>>> getPartitionAssignmentForTopics(final List<String> topics) {
    final scala.collection.Seq<String> seqTopics = scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(topics).toList();
    scala.collection.mutable.Map<String, scala.collection.Map<Object, scala.collection.Seq<Object>>> tmpMap1 =
            zkUtils.getPartitionAssignmentForTopics(seqTopics);

    final java.util.Map<String, java.util.Map<Integer, java.util.List<Integer>>> result = new HashMap<>();
    java.util.Map<String, Map<Object, Seq<Object>>> tmpMap2 = JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(tmpMap1);
    tmpMap2.forEach((k1, v1) -> {
        String topic = (String)k1;
        java.util.Map<Object, Seq<Object>> objectSeqMap = JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(v1);
        java.util.Map<Integer, List<Integer>> tmpResultMap = new HashMap<>();
        objectSeqMap.forEach((k2, v2) -> {
            Integer tmpInt = (Integer)k2;
            List<Integer> tmpList = (List<Integer>)(Object)JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(v2);
            tmpResultMap.put(tmpInt, tmpList);
        });
        result.put(topic, tmpResultMap);
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nothing is really _nice_ when you have to write it in java :( Perhaps, it's time to consider switching to a better language (like scala)? 
Adding some `import` statements on top of the file, and getting rid of package names and unnecessary casts in the code, would make it read a little bit better though.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that there is a scala Map and Java Map :)

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to spell both of them out every time. There is only one place in your snippet, where you would have to reference `scala.collection.Map` ... And even that can be avoided if you just skip `tmpMap` and go directly to `tmpMap2`.